# Waveshare ePaper display via IT8951 hat driver for Raspberry pi 4 model B

Tags: display, spi, driver, hat

I bought the 10.3 epaper display which I am trying drive it from a Raspberry Pi 4. The official wiki instructions (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/10.3inch_e-Paper_HAT) is using BCM2835 which I assume works with older Pi's like 3A, 3B.

The Raspberry Pi 4 is BCM2711. So I downloaded the drivers from https://github.com/waveshareteam/IT8951-ePaper and compile using GPIOD.

```
sudo apt-get install libgpiod-dev
git clone https://github.com/waveshareteam/IT8951-ePaper
cd IT8951-ePaper/Raspberry
make
```

and run `sudo ./epd -1.67 1`.

I don't see any activity on the screen. Are my steps correct? If anyone is using ePaper display can please share their experience that would be helpful.

### Thanks a ton,